# Select lines in canvas

Tags: java, android, canvas, touch, line

I have drawn lines on a canvas by reading a list of Line objects which are basically just x1, y1, x2 and y2.

The image is zoomable and scrollable thanks to a `MatrixGestureDetector` but now I'd like to be able to "select" a line by clicking it. By selecting I mean having it highlighted and either stored in a selected lines list or having a `Boolean` in the attributes of the Line.

I have managed to detect the coordinates of the click and calculate the relative coordinates depending on the scale factor and the translation. I compared the coordinates of my click to the coordinates of all the lines and if the click is on the line it gets wider.

The problem is you have to be so precise it's impossible to select one without zooming as hell and if two lines are too close they both get selected.How could I select only the closest line (in a certain distance around my click)?

Thanks for your help

Answer (score 0):

You can try with some simple math, let's say you have 3 points
A B and C

B and C are your segment and A is the point where the click was made

Distance between B(x1,y1) and A(x2,y2) is sqrt((x1-x2)^2+(y1-y2)^2) lets call it distBA

Distance between C(x1,x2) and A(x2,y2) is again sqrt((x1-x2)^2+(y1-y2)^2) lets call it distCA

now we need another variable masterDistance=distBA+distCA

now you iterate through all your lines and remember the one with the lowest value of masterDistance, that should be your closest line.

You can also verify if it is less than a certain value so you avoid the case where you have 2 lines, one at the top of the screen and one at the bottom and the user clicks in the middle. Without this verification a line will still be selected even tho the click is nowhere near any of the lines.

Comment: http://www.image-heberg.fr/files/1524577106556074865.png

I have thought of this but the problem is the following. Let's say I want to select the right line by clicking really close to it (the red point). The blue distance will be shorter than the green one and the left line will then be selected.

Comment: Didn't think of that. I have 2 more ideas. First is one i dislike and truthfully don't really know how to do it, i need to search. For this you need to know some math to find a perpendicular line between your point and the line and then calculate the distance between that two points, that is the shortest distance between the line and the user selected point. For that you need to know math and i was not a fan of that in highschool but with some google i might be able to do it.

Comment: Yeah that's what I came up with in the end. I think I'm gonna go for this one. Don't worry this is in my range of skills but thanks for your help

Comment: Second, is a hackish idea that eats resources but it is easier with no math knoledge. You iterate trough points on the segment from B to C. Lets say you get the first point, D that is close to B but on the segment. You calculate the distance from your click to the point D and save it distAD. For now masterDistance=distAD. You get another D a little closer to C but still on the segment and if the new distAD is lower than masterDistance then masterDistance=distAD. And from here is like the first example